# Analyzing a likert-type item data with repeated measures with logistic ordinal regression

Tags: multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian, likert, ordered-logit, ordered-probit

I'm analyzing some Likert-type item for my thesis. After a quick research, I figured out, that instead of using a least-squares regression as conventionally, a logit or probit ordinal regression model would be the best option (see Liddell and Kruschke, 2018: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022103117307746?via%3Dihub). Due to repeated measures, I would have to use a hierarchical regression model. All papers I could find used an bayesian approach for analyzing hierarchical ordinal data (for example again Liddell and Kruschke, 2018). I'm not really versed with bayesian statistics, so I wonder if there is any frequentists approach for this kind of analysis.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. I would check out the `ordinal` package if you are familiar with `R`, as it supports both the hierarchical ordered probit and hierarchical ordered logit model. I would also encourage you to consider the `brms` package, as it makes specifying Bayesian models reasonably straightforward.